# Operation overflow not working c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I build a class mapping rational number, and i'd like to implement the multiplication by a scalar operation overflow, something like that :

```
Rational &operator*(Rational const& a, double lambda)
{
    Rational r(a._num * lambda, a._den);
}
```

Where `_num` and `_den` are the numerator and denominator of the rational number.

When I run `cout << r * 45.2;`, I get `-858993460/4389064`. It should be noted that the `operator<<` is working fine on others instances of `Rational`.

How can it's not be working? Thanks :)

Comment: How do you store `Rational`? What type are `_num` and `_den`?

Comment: and what's the value of r in cout?

Comment: I'd hope that modern compilers will find both mistakes in your code and issue warnings for them, did you turn on warnings and consider and understand them?

Comment: _num and _den are both integers, and the value of r is a random test value, in this case it's 2 and 13 for example

Comment: Try (a) compiling this with heightened warnings enabled (as high as you can get on your toolchain), and then (b) *fixing what is flagged.* At least one of the problems is obvious .

Comment: I use Visual Studio, and i get no warnings except from some "Cannot find or open the PDB file." that i always get with any projects

Comment: Hmmm .... seems this question has been marked as a duplicate.   Problem is, the question it is marked as duplicating is a bit different.

Answer (score 6):

`Rational &` -- you're returning a reference to a temporary (undefined behavior) as well as failing to return it. You need:

```
Rational operator*(Rational const& a, double lambda) {
    return Rational(a._num * lambda, a._den);
}
```

I also recommend paying attention to your compiler warnings. The code you had originally should invoke multiple on decent compilers.

Comment: All right, seems like i didn't quite get the concept, i get it now, no references, just the actual variable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When returning references or pointers, you want to make sure that whatever you're returning won't be destroyed when exiting that scope. So when you implement an operator like `operator*=`, that's modifying the left hand side and returning it, so there you do typically return by reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

You don't return anything from that function.
And you can't return references to local variables, so you should probably change the return type to `Rational` (remove the `&`)

Also, it's called "operator overloading"

Answer (score 3):

`operator*()` needs to return a value.    Yours is not.

Any attempt by the caller to use the return value from a function that doesn't return one gives undefined behaviour.

Also, your function returns a reference.   Which is probably not a good idea.

You probably want to do something like

```
Rational operator*(Rational const& a, double lambda)
{
    Rational r(a._num * lambda, a._den);
    return r;
}
```

Note that the return type is a `Rational`, not a reference.   And that it returns the value of `r`.

This assumes that you have implemented the constructor being used to create `r`, and that it works as intended.   You have provided no information that would confirm or deny that assumption.